# Magento2 : What is the default table used by Bestsellers in the admin?

Tags: magento2, best-seller

In the database, I know that there are 3 aggregated bestseller tables

> sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily,
>   sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly,
>   sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly

but which one of them is the
default?

See attached screencast image:https://monosnap.com/file/5N7Q0kR95cDKvjpAeD29MDEAdfxmn6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashboard bestseller usese Report/Bestseller resource model that can be found in:

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers.php
```

And as you can see in constructor that it uses `AGGREGATION_DAILY` by default

```
$this->_init('sales_bestsellers_aggregated_' . self::AGGREGATION_DAILY, 'id');
```

From the look of this, I can say it uses `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily` table for this report

Comment: Thanks, I also confirmed it on my end by checking the code base that the default aggregated bestseller table used is the sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily

Answer (score 1):

The bestsellers table on the dashboard is an "all time" display of data.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products/Ordered.php